# Generating additional SQL rows from columns

Tags: sql, presto

In presto, I have rows of the form

```
name, var1, var2, var3
Foo, A, B, C
```

And because I need to group by var1, and also by var2 and var3 (each separately), I want to transform each row into three rows of the form:

```
name, key
Foo, var1=A
Foo, var2=B
Foo, var3=C
```

So that I can then just group by key. Presto doesn't have an UNPIVOT function, so any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the number of rows by using a cross join to a subquery of the needed number of rows e.g.

```
select
      t.name
    , case when n.n = 1 then t.var1
           when n.n = 2 then t.var2
           when n.n = 3 then t.var3
      end as key
from sourcetbl t
cross join (
       select 1 as n union all
       select 2 as n union all
       select 3 as n
       ) n
```

and then a case expression may be used to reduce the number of columns based on the supplied "row number" (`n.n` in my example)

Comment: `CROSS JOIN UNNEST(ARRAY[var1, var2, var3]) AS u(key)` would be a more direct approach.

Comment: Why is it "more direct"? What benefit does it provide?  (unnest array is a valid alternative, but not typical sql)